# Best event for QtableWidget to add subrecords in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, relational-database, psycopg2, qtablewidget

I have a relational database with 2 related tables.
Also `psycopg2` adapter were used to retrieve data.There are two `QtableWidget` to display data from two related tables in ui.
What is the appropriate event (from `QtableWidget` events) to detect new record is selected or filled into main `QtableWidget` to proceed second query and filling sub records into other `QtableWidget`?

```
self.tableWidget.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.main_table_current_row_changed)
```

the above event were used but just user click is necessary.
Any idea is apreciated.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to connect to the [itemSelectionChanged](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html#itemSelectionChanged) signal.

```
def __init__(...)
    ...
    self.table1.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.update_table2)

def update_table2(self):
    items = self.table1.selectedItems()
    # Update table2 based on table1 selection
```

Comment: Hi Brendan Abel, The connection between event and function has been established successfully. but the question is:                                        which event is the best to call a function that fills second table with related records.

Comment: @user3786145  That's what my question answers (technically, it's a signal, not an event) -- use the `itemSelectionChanged` signal.